# Validating data before filling DataTable?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

The following code takes an Excel file and loads it into a DataTable. If the values in the file's columns don't match the DataTable columns' DataType, the program throws a `System.ArgumentException`.

For example, the QTY column in the DataTable is `Int32` but row 5 in the spreadsheet has a value of 40O instead of 400. How can I check the data before or while it's being loaded into the DataTable, and inform the user which row/column has the invalid value?

```
//"file" = c:\myfile.xlsx

string strConn = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + file + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;TypeGuessRows=0;ImportMixedTypes=Text\"", file);

using (OleDbConnection dbConnection = new OleDbConnection(strConn))
{
    using (OleDbDataAdapter dbAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]", dbConnection))
    {
        dbAdapter.Fill(InputTable);
    }
}
```

The columns are:

```
ColumnName    DataType  
ID            System.String  
QTY           System.Int32  
DOS           System.DateTime
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case you're not going to be able to perform this type of validation unless you base the `DataTable`. Further, the only way you're going to be able to get at that array, before it fails, is to *hide* a method like `LoadDataRow`. In short, it's really not realistic to capture this the way you're loading data right now.

One thing to consider is this. Rather than leveraging `Fill`, get a `DbDataReader` and run through each row manually. This would allow you to do something like this:

```
int val;
if (!int.TryParse(qtyValFromReaderRow, out val))
{
    // handle the error
}
```

Comment: Thank you .. I'm looking into that now. So basically go through the `DbDataReader` line by line, validate, and then add that row to the `DataTable` ?

Comment: @JeffBrady, that's absolutely right! You should be able to use either `LoadRow` or `ImportRow` and pass it a simple `object[]`.

Comment: Got it .. I rewrote my code to use `DbDataReader`, create a `DataRow` and do `DataTable.Rows.Add(DataRow)` and it works. Now I just need to write the validations for each `DataRow` item and I should be ok. Thanks again!

Comment: @JeffBrady, no worries, and I'm glad I could be of assistance!